# Django using model of one app into other app's model

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-apps, django-1.3

Salam and hi,

I am using django and breaking two parts of project in two apps. However there is a reference field of one table as foreign key of other in terms of db. So how can I use one app's model primary key as foreign key of another app's model? And if is not possible then should I just make single app of all such apps. I am actually thinking apps as different modules/components of project, may be I will be adding some apps in future.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either import the model from the other app, or refer to it by name in a string.

Comment: so then will I be able to use it like `models.ForeignKey('importedModelName')` ?

Comment: If you import the model then you can use the reference directly.

Comment: use the reference directly like I wrote in last in above line? like
`models.ForeignKey(className)` ?

Comment: ok got it so after importing it will be similar to any other class/model inside that models file, thanks