# In Django get a reference to a model in another app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models

I imagined this would be relatively straight forward but I cannot find a solution. I have two apps 'library' and 'counts'. I want to get a reference to a model in 'library' from inside 'counts'. Both apps are registered in settings.INSTALLED_APPS.
My project is in a virtualenv named 'slideaudit'. In that is the project folder named 'src'. My apps live under 'src' as well as the conf folder.
I imagined I would write something similar to:
from project_name.app_name.models import model_name

Whilst there appears to be considerable posts on the issue I haven't found one that does the job. Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you configured BASE_DIR constant in settings.py?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django using model of one app into other app's model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024927/django-using-model-of-one-app-into-other-apps-model)

Comment: If your apps live inside `src`, then surely you should use `src` in the path you're trying to import, no?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by reference:

1. If you want simply to do: `from app1.models import MyModel1` this does not need any special configuration: just add app1 to `INSTALLED_APPS` and django will directly recognize it.
2. But if you mean by reference **Foreign Key** you don't event need to import your model, you do just as follow:

   ```
   class NyModel2(model.Model):
       field = models.ForeignKey("app1.MyModel1", verbose_name="my_model1", related_name="my_models2")
   ```

   - django will understand that you need model `MyModel1` from `app1`
   - related_name attribute specifies the name of the reverse relation which means `my_model1.my_models2.all()` return all the **MyModel2** instance that have **my_model1** as foreign key.

Comment: It is the 'Foreign Key reference I am referring to. Appreciate you highlighting both methods.

Comment: Also - I am using PyCharm. When I use: from app1.models import MyModel1 in app2 (models or views), PyCharm reports an 'Unresolved reference'. However, it works perfectly fine. I was trusting PyCharm to tell me if everything was okay and whilst it does a good job it's not 100% accurate it would seem.

Comment: if you are using a virtual environment you should configure that in PyCharm, so he can identify the apps path, otherwise you can check the PyCharm forum I'm sure you can find a better answer there ;)

Comment: Please nore its `app_label.model_name` NOT `app_name.model_name`, its easy to get them confused if they are different.